# CGroup perm for every user in gid

Tags: linux, debian, cgroups

i need every user in group users can work with the following cgroup 'shol'. Here is my cgconfig.conf, if i use the code i can't run with my users in group users gexec.

```
group shol {
    perm {
        task {
            gid = users;
        }
    }
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = "1G";
  }
}
```

if i use with an user in group users the following command

```
cgexec -g memory:1024 ./test.sh
```

i get this:

```
cgroup change of group failed
```

How can i set the permission, that all users can put there pids in the task file for limiting the processes.